# Set Terraform variable only on initial creation

Tags: terraform

I wonder if it's possible to set the value of a Terraform variable if a given resource was already created or not.

My Terraform project manages a number of stateless resources, but also one stateful resource: the DB. The first time the infrastructure is put in place, we want to initialize (import) the DB, but not the next times (when the stateless assets are upgraded according to the Terraform declarations). This import is done by the User Data script of an EC2 instance (edit: the EC2 instance is stateless, we put the DB import command in its user_data out of convenience and to limit the access to RDS DB from the EC2 instance).

It's not obvious for us to detect in the User Data script if it's the first time or not (it would require development). So now I can see two options:

- In the script that calls the `terraform apply`, I can query the Terraform state (`terraform state list`) to determine if the DB already exists, and pass it to `terraform apply` as a variable.
- But it would be simpler if it was possible directly in the Terraform declarations to determine the current state of the DB resource (does it exist or not), so I could pass it to my User Data script (so it initializes the DB or not). I did not see how to do that. I could not see any function, and it looks like when I reference to an attribute of a resource (ex: the ID of the RDS DB) it will be computed after the creation of the resource.

Would you know if my second point is possible?

Comment: No. There is no functionality in tf to determine if something exists or not, unless you implement some custom solution for that.

Comment: The question is a bit too abstract and lacking in other relevant information. If your only managed stateful resource is a RDS, then why is there a `user_data`? That would imply an instance is also managed, which is stateful. Also, presumably stateless resources can be given state either by the provider or within the Terraform config to ensure their idempotence, and then you would have more options available.

Comment: The EC2 instance itself is not stateful (our server app is running on it, it does not store any data on its disk and can be destroyed/recreated). We currently use its `user_data` to run the initial import (among other init such as configuration files customisation for the instance itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally-speaking, from Terraform's own perspective it's the responsibility of the remote objects being managed (possibly with the help of the relevant provider) to deal with concerns like taking actions only on initial creation, if such a thing is meaningful for a particular object.

For example, from Terraform's perspective `user_data` is just an arbitrary string to be passed in to the AWS provider, and the AWS provider in turn treats it as an arbitrary string to be passed to the AWS API, and the AWS API in turn treats it as an arbitrary string that software in the EC2 instance can retrieve. But since the software running in your EC2 instance *can* retain state (on disk), *that software* can potentially keep track of the concept of "first boot" vs. "subsequent boot", and take different actions depending on that. Many AMIs include [CloudInit](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/) as the software which interprets `user_data`, and indeed that software *does* keep track of first boot vs. subsequent boot so that some of its modules can behave differently between the two situations.

Whether that sort of model can apply to other resource types will depend on what capabilities the corresponding remote object has or what additional capabilities the Terraform provider for that system has layered on top of the remote system capabilities. For example, *in principle* the resource type implementation for a database instance could include some arguments which are only considered during initial creation, although I don't know if the specific resource types you are using have such a capability.

With that said, a database is *naturally* a stateful object and so it's presumably possible to directly inspect it to decide whether it's been populated yet or not, without Terraform's help. I think the most robust answer to your underlying problem would be for the system that's responsible for populating the database to first connect to the database and see if it's already been populated, and do nothing if so. That way the source of truth for the state of the database is the database itself, and you won't need to deal with awkward situations where a proxy for that information (e.g. in Terraform state) might be out of sync with reality.

Comment: I agree that the component that is responsible of the DB (in my case the server application and its initialization script located in the user data) should be responsible of managing the state of the DB, so there would be one source of truth.
I did not do that because of the complexity to that in server app. I think I'll use a tactical solution (with `terraform state`) until we implement another planned improvement of the DB import.